# Is there any other alternative function for getimagesize() to check whether an image exists?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a Image Search Engine but my database has many broken image links. I want to filter the records and only show those which are working.

I tried getimagesize() function as shown in the code below but it takes too much time, I want it to be faster since it will affect user experience. To check whether the image files still exist at the URI, I tried file_exists(), get_headers() as well, but they don't work or stop after just showing one image.

```
$_sql2="select * from imgdata where stitle like '%".$search."%'";
                $rs2=mysqli_query($_con,$_sql2);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($rs2)<1)
                                 {
                                  echo "<center><h4><b>Oops! No result found for your query</b></h4></center>";
                                  exit();
                                 }
                while($resul2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2))
                {                   
                    if(@getimagesize(''.$resul2['simg'].''))
                    {
                        echo "<a href='".$resul2['slink']."'><img src='".$resul2['simg']."' height='100px' id='imgp'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }                    
                    }
```

I want my website to be faster but the website takes too much time as of now. I have to wait at least 10 minutes for all images to load properly. Please suggest an alternative way to filter the images.

Comment: If you are talking about external images, there’s probably not much you can do to speed this up - making HTTP requests simply is a very costly thing. But you should probably not do this in the frontend to begin with - but rather clear your database of those invalid entries using some background task that runs periodically.

Comment: 10 minutes!? How many images are you loading? Would pagination be a better option here?